# Django REST api Parent and child componet to use react js form submit as it is DRA?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

guys i am beginner React js.

i want get as it is rest API drop-down list box have to create in react. so how to do it ?
could you guy please give way method

[image: Django REST API Form]

Answer (score -1):

here in react you just working with the front-end so you don't have to worry about the back-end just design you front normally

```
<select>
  <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
  <option value="lime">Lime</option>
  <option selected value="coconut">Coconut</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>
```

if you want to extract this one as a component and use it somewhere else you need to define a list of value to replace it with your current values anyhow it will be static at the end

Comment: How to do *Back-end API* extract and get same value drop-down list box ? could you give example please ?